# What library is used to access SQLite in my application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

My little SQLite testing application is working, and everything is 100% functioning as expected.

For learning purposes, I'd like to know what library is allowing me to communicate with my Scans.db SQLite database. I was told that I'd need the System.Data.SQLite reference, but my application works and I don't see it referenced anywhere.

My guess is that Entity Framework is somehow wrapping this?

Here's a picture of my current solution:

[image]

Can someone share some light on this? What library is actually letting me access the database?

Comment: I swear to moses this is my solution! How can I find the connection string of my Model2.edmx so I can paste it here?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, you can find it in the settings file (in the Properties folder). But Pieter deleted his comment anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the ADO.NET provider for SQLite is properly installed, your project doesn't need to reference it explicitly, because the only SQLite-specific bit of your program is the connection string. Entity Framework knows where to find the provider, based on the information in the machine.config file. It wouldn't work if the provider weren't installed, of course...

Comment: Yes, I did download this file: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/. So would you recommend I use a regular library reference to System.Data.SQLite so when I create an installation project it packages everything up nicely?

Comment: That would probably be the simplest option. Otherwise, you need to explicitly include System.Data.SQLite.dll in your installation package.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Data.SQLite` assembly is used to access SQLite database from .NET. The assembly contains the unmanaged driver as embedded resource.  It is possible that the assembly is installed in the GAC if not present in the `bin` folder but impossible to connect whitout it.

Answer (score 0):

System.Data.SQLite is enough for SQLite to work. If your application works without even refering System.Data.SQLite in your application, then the SQLite might got installed with any other application like SQLite Admin tool or so.